# Combining a drop-down with autocomplete and search

Tags: search, dropdown, autocomplete

Recently I was faced with the following dilemma.
By trying to combine a drop-down that must contain items with a top search/type field (autocomplete and search) inside of the drop-down I realised that the user may get confused. Despite I know this piece of Ui is used in many websites and applications what is your opinion when after you select and choose an option you must also display the results.

I attach my case study examples.

[image: Case 1]

[image: Case 2]

[image: Case 3]

[image: Case 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where a proper label helps. In your example, you have no labels above to indicate *what* you're asking the user to select.

You're correct in that this is a common UI control. You have a couple of abilities and indicators you can add here; allowing a 'clear' function, and proper labeling.

You don't need the additional 'please select' instructions inside the dropdown. If it's a complex instruction or reason, you can make the label clearer, or even add 'hint text' below the dropdown, so users can have some clarity.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much. This, is why I wanted to put this to the UX Design Dev community. I think the UI has potential but, if the design is not correct can lead to confusion.